Document `APIView` 400 responses with `drf-standardized-errors` and `drf-spectacular`
Is it possible to use drf-standardized-errors with drf-spectacular to document the validation_error type errors generated by an APIView that manually uses a serialiser to validate GET parameters?
I have a basic APIView that accepts a series of GET parameters and returns a single value - the result of a calculation based on the provided parameters. I manually use a serialiser to validate the parameters prior to using them, thus the view can return a standardised 400 response containing validation_error type errors. However, this type of error response is not documented by drf-spectacular for this view. Other views, defined using ViewSet and declared serialisers, have their 400 responses documented correctly.
APIView obviously does not support declaring a serialiser, so I use the following to have both the parameters and the view's 200 response documented according to the definition of the relevant serialisers:
@extend_schema(
    parameters=[
        ParameterSerializer
    ],
    response={
        status.HTTP_200_OK: ResultSerializer
    }   
)
class PriceLookupView(views.APIView):
    
    def get(self, request):
        ...

This generates the documentation as I would expect, apart from the 400 response, which only contains the client_error type.
The above does generate a warning about not being able to guess a serialiser. So, following its suggestion, I have also tried using GenericAPIView and declaring serializer_class, despite it not being utilised by DRF itself:
class PriceLookupView(generics.GenericAPIView):
    
    serializer_class = ParameterSerializer

This does not alter the output of the generated documentation. In my experimentation, the serialiser declared on the class in this approach seems to control the documentation of the view's 200 response only.
I haven't been able to find any info on this use case - which makes me think I'm either not using the right keywords, or the solution is so obvious it hasn't been asked before and I'm just missing something simple. Is this possible?
